# OpenNETCF Send Method in Ping class

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I'm kinda new so it is just a simple code to test in C# (WIndow CE Version 2.0). I would like to know why, in OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation, the Send(string) method in Ping class cannot send IP? It shows error (PingException was unhandled - impossible to send a packet) whereas when i change namespace to System.Net.NetworkInformation, it works perfectly. Can anyone help to explain? Cause i'm dealing with Window CE (version 2.0) where System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace can't be used. Thanks in advanced.

```
 bool result = false;
        Ping ping = new Ping();

        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("12.35.146.98");

        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            result = true;

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Window CE - .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what is the problem already. The error is due to "missing coredll" which requires you to use emulator to test out the program. If use emulator, there is no error.