# failed try: OpenNETCF Send Method in Ping class

Tags: c#, networking, compact-framework, opennetcf

I have tried to ping with OpenNETCF like Mr."CNLSH" in this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685515/opennetcf-send-method-in-ping-class)   and it works fine if the host is available. If not, pingReply.Status never becomes false because i'll get an exception from send-Method (could not send package). Is there a possibility to work without try/catch?

```
    public static bool pingIP(String s_ip)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply;
        try
        {
            pingReply = ping.Send(s_ip,500);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("could not connect to " + s_ip);
            return false;
        }
        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to catch the exceptions. 
Also, the Ping class is disposable, so you should dispose of it when you're finished.

```
using(Ping ping = new Ping())
{
    /* ... */
}
```

see: http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7555257b-b797-37d3-ff61-4e90f731be99.htm